# How can I validate if a string is a correct Netsuite Consumer client key/secret?

Tags: key, token, netsuite, credentials

As part of our Netsuite integration process... we ask our user (human) to create the

- Client consumer key
- Client consumer secret
- Token id
- Token secret

Then, he copy and pastes those credentials into our site.

My question is... how can I validate the string that he pasted... and check if it's a correct key/secret?
Is there any pattern? string size?

What happened onces... is one client copied a key without the first letter.
The integration failed. We weren't sure why, until we asked him to re-generate the token credentials again.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware: NO.

If there were a common pattern that existed, I would imagine it would increase the chances of someone or something compromising the security of the site. Even if there were a way to verify, there's no actual way to verify the encryption method used for the credentials anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> What happened onces... is one client copied a key without the first letter. The integration failed. We weren't sure why, until we asked him to re-generate the token credentials again.

If this is the reason you want a validation , then why dont you just go to setup - > user/roles ->view login audit trail and click advanced search . Then in the results add details and token based application name .

Any failed attempt will show up in there and you can also have this search in your dashboard with details explaining the reason why :)

To validate a consumer key really depends to the context of the service , i would check if NS provides keys in a specific length and filter through that although the first approach seems more efficient and simple .